# Can't read data that was written with writeToFile:atomically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have these 2 lines of code:

```
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somepath.com/first.plist"]] writeToFile:@"first.plist" atomically:YES];
NSDictionary *dTmp=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

But my dTmp is null. I'm not specifying any path, so it's supposed to be stored in the root directory, right?
What is my mistake?

Comment: You can't write in mainBundle.

Comment: You can write file in `NSDocumentDirectory`/ `NSCachedDirectory`

Comment: Thanks both, I'm going to check this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

You should not use synchronous networking calls like `dataWithContentsOfURL`. it willl block the UI. Look at NSURLSession instead.

You can't write to a file in the root directory. iOS apps are limited to a few sandbox directories like the apps' documents and caches directories.

You should write code that writes and reads to one of your allowed sandbox directories.

Also, don't write compound statements. It makes it hard to read and debug. Do one thing on each line.

Check the return value at each step to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, it was just for testing, I didn't know i could not write in the root.